# Regular Expression. Is it possible to match (a or b) and (a or c) and (a or d) but not aaa?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to censor a dirty word. Users can replace some characters by *.

Let's take a word "dog", for example (this is not dirty, of course)

1. *og
2. d*g
3. do*
4. d**

and so on

Regex looks like `(d|\*)(o|\*)(g|\*)`

Is it possible to match all variants above but not '***'?

Comment: While you technically don't need lookahead, your RE will become inconventiently large if you don't (`([d*][o*]g|[d*]o[g*]|d[o*][g*]`).

Comment: How do you know the dog isn't dirty?  Mine get muddy *extremely* quickly....  :-P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Python has negative lookahead assertions.  You want to match `[d*][o*][g*]` and `(?!\*{3})`:

```
(?!\*{3})[d*][o*][g*]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?!\**$)[dog*]+$
```

You can try something like this using `lookahead`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/hE4jH0/23

Comment: With this, you will also have to add `(?!d*$)(?!o*$)...` - too many exceptions are necessary with this regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this regex:

```
^\w{0,3}\*{0,2}\w{0,3}(?!\*)
```